# What happened to the i2s pins which are in RPI B board and not in RPI B+ board

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, data-transfer, pi-models, wolfson-audio-card

I'm working on RPI model B board.I've a driver for wolfson audio card,Which uses i2s pins for data transfer.Now i need to work on RPI B+ model.But there are no i2s pins in model B+.What i need to do to make my driver work on both model B and model B+ and how the data transfer from audio card to the new RPI B+ model board?

Comment: Have you asked Wolfson?  I'm not sure that the card is usable on the B+ as I thought it used the now missing P5 header.  Wolfson will give you a definitive answer.  The gpios still exist, they just aren't brought out to P5.

Comment: There is now a [new card](http://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-accessories/cirrus_logic_audio_card) which has come out since Wolfson was acquired by Cirrus Logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 appearances of the PCM pins on BMC_GPIO 28-31 ALT2 (on the B P5 header) and BMC_GPIO 18-21 ALT0 which are on the B+ P1 header. There would need to be some configuration changes and the pins are not grouped together like on P5.